# Versatile string validation

Tags: c#, interview-questions, validation

I passed a technical test the other day, one part included a cheap string validation and I am wondering this can be further improved to be more versatile to requirement changes.

The requirements were something like that

> Create a `Validate` method, which accepts a string and returns `true` if it's valid and `false` if it's not.
>
> A string is valid if it satisfies the rules below:
>
> - The string must be at least 6 characters long and not exceed 16 characters.
> - The string must contain only letters, numbers and optionally one hyphen (-).
> - The string must start with a letter, and must not end with a hyphen.
>     For example, `validate("Michelle Belle");` would return false because it contains a space.

My solution was like that:

```
public static class ComparableExtensions
{
    public static bool IsStrictlyLowerThan<TComparable>(this TComparable comparable, TComparable value)
        where TComparable : IComparable<TComparable>
    {
        return comparable.CompareTo(value) < 0;
    }

    public static bool IsStrictlyGreaterThan<TComparable>(this TComparable comparable, TComparable value)
        where TComparable : IComparable<TComparable>
    {
        return comparable.CompareTo(value) > 0;
    }

    public static bool IsStrictlyNotBetween<TComparable>(this TComparable comparable, TComparable lowerBound, TComparable upperBound)
        where TComparable : IComparable<TComparable>
    {
        if (lowerBound.IsStrictlyGreaterThan(upperBound))
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(lowerBound) + nameof(upperBound));                
        }

        return comparable.IsStrictlyLowerThan(lowerBound) || comparable.IsStrictlyGreaterThan(upperBound);
    }
}

public static class CharExtensions
{
    public static bool IsLetterOrDigit(this char c)
    {
        return char.IsLetterOrDigit(c);
    }

    public static bool IsLetter(this char c)
    {
        return char.IsLetter(c);
    }

    public static bool IsHyphen(this char c)
    {
        return c == '-';
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public static bool Validate(string str)
    {
        if (str.Length.IsStrictlyNotBetween(6, 16))
        {
            return false;
        }

        if (!str.First().IsLetter() || str.Last().IsHyphen())
        {
            return false;
        }

        var hyphenCount = 0;

        for (var i = 1; i < str.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            if (str[i].IsLetterOrDigit())
            {
                continue;
            }
            if (str[i].IsHyphen())
            {
                hyphenCount++;
                if (hyphenCount > 1)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

I purposefully decided to not go with Regular Expressions to keep the logic readable and I am wondering if my code can be further refactored to incorporate new business rules.

Comment: I'd be good idea to take a look a this question [Enforcing string validity with the C# type system](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/208291/enforcing-string-validity-with-the-c-type-system) and its answers.

Comment: Would the regular expression for these rules really be that unreadable?

Comment: @t3chb0t I am gonna check this out, thanks!

Comment: @Kenneth K well at the beginning it's fine but if it starts piling up new business rules it can be a pain to go through all of them

Comment: Why do you have all of those "extentions"? They make the code way harder to read! `IsHyphen`? `IsStrictlyGreaterThan`? Why? Just write `== '-'` in the code itself.

Comment: @ToddSewell for the grand sake of consistency ;-), I was thinking the solution as a starter for new business rules which would also leverage extension methods, and trying to make specification pattern somehow emerge from that.

Comment: Your solution reminds me of the [Enterprise Rules Engine](https://thedailywtf.com/articles/The_Enterprise_Rules_Engine). (That is not a good thing.)

Comment: @EhouarnPerret yeah, please as little extra code as possible (YAGNI). those extension methods have similar names, so sure, they're kinda readable, but considering they do very little, I'd say you should leave them out in this case

Comment: To me, this huge overkilling with the comparables and charextentions makes it very unreadable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not much to say about the extensions methods, as they are mostly wrappers.

However if you're looking for ways to make the algorithm more readable, LINQ is your friend. You can replace most of your logic with a one-liner:

> ```
> var hyphenCount = 0;
>
> for (var i = 1; i < str.Length - 1; i++)
> {
>     if (str[i].IsLetterOrDigit())
>     {
>         continue;
>     }
>     if (str[i].IsHyphen())
>     {
>         hyphenCount++;
>         if (hyphenCount > 1)
>         {
>             return false;
>         }
>     }
>     else
>     {
>         return false;
>     }
> }
>
> return true;
> ```

Like this:

```
return str.All(c => c.IsHyphen() || c.IsLetterOrDigit()) && str.Count(c => c.IsHyphen()) <= 1;
```

Which more clearly explains your intent, you can also move those expression to their separate methods to make it as readable as possible, this way you can keep adding new conditions, without modifying the existing logic (unless they interfere with one another that is).

Answer (score 8):

- There's a bug: you're not checking if the last character is a letter or digit, only that it isn't a hyphen, so this fails to reject `"abcdef&"`. Denis' solution may be less efficient (2 iterations instead of 1), but with at most 16 characters that's not much of a concern, and it's both easier to read and it works correctly.
- The first two rules read very nicely. I especially like that the business rules are translated to code almost 1:1, that will make updating easier. However, I do think those extension methods are over-engineered. `str.Length < 6 || str.Length > 16` and `!char.IsLetter(str.First()) || str.Last() == '-'` is already quite readable, and that doesn't require extra code that needs to be understood and maintained.
- You can use `=>` syntax for methods with single-expression bodies.

Comment: I agree on the extension methods part, another positive for using standard types and methods is that, experienced developers, know right away the way they function.

Comment: @Pieter Witvoet true, my bad, wrong copy and paste =/

Answer (score 7):

Little bit late but let me add *another* alternative solution, t3chb0t already took care of your code.

You have extension methods for `IComparable<T>` and `Char`, this forces you to write your *business logic* in code instead of a (pseudo) high-level language which resembles your business rules. If you do not want to use a regular expression (I'd use it) then you should try to match 1:1 the language of your requirements:

```
StringValidator.Validate(str)
    .LengthIsInRange(6, 16)
    .ContainsOnly(Matches.LetterOrDigits, Matches.Hyphen).HasAtMost(1, Matches.Hyphen)
    .StartsWith(Matches.Letter)
    .DoesNotEndWith(Matches.Hyphen);
```

This is simple enough to be self-describing. Does it hurt performance? Maybe but it's seldom a problem in LoB applications and business rules can become incredibly convoluted. Is it a problem? Measure it, for performance critical code it's easy to write an extension method (for `StringValidator`) to perform a specific task.

Note that I'm using an hypothetical `Matches.LetterOrDigits()` function with `string -> bool` signature instead of, let's say, `Char.IsLetterOrDigit()` with `char -> bool`. Why? Because not every *character* (OK, I won't repeat this again...) is a single `Char` then you have to compare strings (few examples: <kbd>à</kbd> or <kbd>dž</kbd> or ).

Your **requirements are, probably, vague** and your code broken regardless the interpretation you picked. What do they mean with *letter*? An US-ASCII Latin character? In that case your code is wrong because <kbd>ā</kbd> (LATIN SMALL LETTER A MACRON) is accepted. Is is a *letter* everything in the *Letter* Unicode category (or even just in the *Latin Extended* Unicode block)? Your code is wrong again because <kbd>ā</kbd> (LATIN SMALL LETTER A + COMBINING MACRON) is rejected. This very example can be solved normalizing the string before starting the validation but it's not always that easy.

Imagine that instead of a single validation rule you have...1,000 of them. Or 10,000. I'm not a fan of extension method for primitive types (especially when they're trivial) but the *mistake* (IMHO) is to work with a **too low level of abstraction**: you do not want to *extend* `String.Length` to replicate what `>` does: you want to extend `String` to support high level composable and chainable assertions.

Note: `ContainsOnly()` may even accept regexes, pseudo code:

```
static ContainsOnly(this StringValidator validator, ...string[] matches) => ...

static class Matches {
    public static string LetterOrDigit = "a-zA-Z0-9";
}
```

Composition should now be fast enough even when you cannot really ignore performance (and you can always have a `MatchRegEx()` extension method).

---

How to extend this? In previous example I assumed a pseudo-implementation like this:

```
public StringValidator LengthInRange(int min, int max) {
    if (IsValid) {
        IsValid = Value.Length >= min && Value.Length <= max;
    }

    return this;
}
```

You can easily extend it to run all validators to generate a list of errors:

```
var result = StringValidator.Validate(str)
    .LengthIsInRange(6, 16)
    .StartsWith(Matches.Letter)
    .DoesNotEndWith(Matches.Hyphen);

if (result.HasErrors)
    Console.WriteLine(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, result.Errors));
```

Or to throw an exception:

```
StringValidator.Validate(str)
    .LengthIsInRange(6, 16)
    .StartsWith(Matches.Letter)
    .DoesNotEndWith(Matches.Hyphen)
    .ThrowIfInvalid();
```

I think you've got the point.

Comment: So if, for example, length is not between 6 and 16 this throws an exception?

Comment: No as per requirements it should return false (the other validators simply fall through after the first one marked the result as invalid?). You can throw explicitly or with an option in `Configure()` or with a call to `ThrowIfInvalid()`. For a future requirement it may add an `IEnumerable<string>` property to collect all errors (for example)

Answer (score 5):

I think you've seen enough alternative solutions so I'll just review your code.

- You should not invent new terms for `x < 0` like `IsStrictlyLowerThan` as this makes things unnecessarily more difficult to understand. Instead, you should stick to the well known naming. In this case that would be `IsLessThan` or in case of `x <= 0` it would be `IsLessThanOrEqual` - Everyone who write code would understand these without any further explanation. Or in case of `IsStrictlyNotBetween` should be `IsNotInRangeExclusive` etc.
- There are voices in comments that suggest using `== '-'` instead of your extensions. I don't agree with that. Your extensions are much better because they make the code look clean and consistent. Having extensions for some operations and not for others would make it look dirty.
- I don't however agree with your decision for not using Regex. With regex it's usually simpler and easier to express complex validations. It's also easier to make your validations case-insensitive or match other patterns or use such services as [regex101.com](https://regex101.com) to test them. It might be enough for now but sooner or later you will need it so don't be so strict about always consider other solutions.
- Keep also in mind that your `IsStrictlyLowerThan` APIs are currently case sensitive so you might consider using `IEqualityComparer<string>` as the last argument and not the `TComparable` that doesn't offer you any additional functionality in this context. So your API should have signatures similar to this one:

  ```
  public static bool IsLessThan(this string value, string other, IComparer<string> comaprer = default)
  {
      return (comaprer ?? StringComparer.Ordinal).Compare(value, other) < 0;
  }
  ```

  Then you can use it with other comparers if necessary, e.g.:

  ```
  "FOO".IsLessThan("foo", StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
  ```

Answer (score 2):

N.B. I thought I'd answer the original test question myself in F# as a Kata, so this is a functional suggestion based on what I found.

I'll only talk about the versatility part of the solution, others have touched on using Linq and I think your code is already quite readable.

---

If you can divide the original requirement into a number of smaller rules, where each rule has the same "Shape".

This "Shape" is *take a sequence of characters and return a Boolean*.

So in C# we'd have:

```
bool LengthIsValid(string s) => s.Length >= 6 && s.Length <= 16;

bool Rule2(string s) => true; //e.g must start with Letter, or doesn't with with '-'
```

Now that we have each rule in the same "Shape", you can create a composite set of rules and validate them all together:

```
var rules = new List<Func<string, bool>> 
{ 
    LengthIsValid, 
    Rule2,
    //etc.
};
```

Checking the rules is then just a matter of applying those rules to the input string:

```
bool CheckAllRules (string s) =>
    rules
    .All(rule => rule(s));
```

With this approach you get versatility from been able to create any number of composition of rules.

e.g. Creating Rules where the powerUsers don't need to check the length (I can be `root`).

```
IEnumerable<Func<string, bool>> CreateRules(bool powerUser)
{
    if (!powerUser)
        yield return LengthIsValid;

    yield return Rule2;
}
```

<sub>The F# version if you're interested in [here](https://gist.github.com/xdaDaveShaw/a21142852d1bf9aff772b07e2523a946)</sub>

Comment: In C# you might want to write `rules.All(x => x(s))` (unless you want to evaluate all the rules without stopping with the first failed one).

Comment: It's OK, because LINQ is lazy evaluated "All" will only keep pulling whilst the predicate returns "true", as soon the result of the predicate is "false" it will stop iterating through the rules. The "select" code only executes when "All" asks for the one more item.
Try changing it to `.Select(rule => { Console.WriteLine("test"); return rule(s); })` and you will only see one "test" if the first rule fails.

Comment: Yep, I worded that very poorly. The two parts of my comments were unrelated. 1) you don't need `Select()` and 2) unless you want to extract them all (but in that case you obviously need `ToArray()` or similar before `All()`).

Comment: Yes, I have a habit of using .Select and .Where followed by .Any/All/Single.First/etc. - it usually makes things clearer for me :) In this case, I think you're correct that just .All would suffice.

Answer (score 1):

About versatility my thought is a separate class to stipulate the different possible rules:

```
class ValidationRules
{
    public const char HYPHEN = '-';
    public readonly int hyphenCount;
    public readonly bool needUpper;
    public readonly bool needLower;
    public readonly bool needDigit;
    public readonly bool allowSpaces;
    public readonly int minLength;
    public readonly int maxLength;
    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor with min and max length and default rules:
    /// needUpper = true
    /// needLower = true
    /// allowSpaces = false
    /// hyphenCount = 1;
    /// </summary>
    public ValidationRules(int minLength, int maxLength)
    {
        this.minLength = minLength;
        this.maxLength = maxLength;
        hyphenCount = 1;
        needLower = true;
        needUpper = true;
        needDigit = true;
        allowSpaces = false;
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor with min and max length and supplied rules:
    /// </summary>
    public ValidationRules(int minLength, int maxLength, int hyphenCount, bool needUpper, bool needLower, bool needDigit, bool allowSpaces)
    {
        this.minLength = minLength;
        this.maxLength = maxLength;
        this.hyphenCount = hyphenCount;
        this.needLower = needLower;
        this.needUpper = needUpper;
        this.needDigit = needDigit;
        this.allowSpaces = allowSpaces;
    }
}
```

the method to validate is still quite simple:

```
/// <summary>
/// Validate string according to validation rules
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
public static bool Validate(string input,ValidationRules rules)
{
   if(input.Length < rules.minLength || input.Length > rules.maxLength)
    {
        return false;
    }
   if(!Char.IsLetter(input[0]) || input[input.Length-1] == ValidationRules.HYPHEN)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return input.Count(x => x == ValidationRules.HYPHEN) <= rules.hyphenCount && input.All(x => 
                                            (rules.needUpper && char.IsUpper(x)) || 
                                            (rules.needLower && char.IsLower(x)) || 
                                            (rules.allowSpaces && char.IsWhiteSpace(x)) ||
                                            (rules.needDigit && char.IsDigit(x)) ||
                                            (x == ValidationRules.HYPHEN));
}
```

Comment: I like your approach!

Comment: For an approach that targets extendability, it will quickly become a mini god class, requiring changes on several different locations. Multiple types with a single visitor would be much better off SOLID and elegance-wise.

Comment: @Denis actually I was thinking about a set of rules that could be built out of a builder: https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation

Comment: @EhouarnPerret That's similar to what I meant, but this implementation would add way too much overhead for such a simple task, if it were an interview question, you should also consider time. Show off some techniques but don't overdo it.

Answer (score 1):

Stop it. Just stop it. Unless you have some kind of unusual performance requirements, **keep it simple**:

```
/// <summary>
/// Regular expression pattern that matches strings containing only Unicode
/// letters, digits, and hyphens.
/// </summary>
public static Regex AllUnicodeLettersNumsHyphen = new Regex(@"^[\p{L}\p{Nd}-]*$");

public static bool IsValid(string s)
{
    return (
        s.Length >= 6 && s.Length <= 16
        && AllUnicodeLettersNumsHyphen.IsMatch(s)
        && s.Count(c => c == '-') <= 1
        && Char.IsLetter(s, 0)
        && s[s.Length - 1] != '-'
    );
}
```

(Those parentheses are optional. I find them visually appealing. Follow your group's coding guidelines on style choices like that.)

Given the requirements you specify, there's no reason for loops, extension methods, or *any* of that stuff. I promise you that 2 years down the line, anyone reading this code (including you!) will be much happier understanding the 5 liner than your code. The smaller the scope the better when you're reading. It will take someone 30 seconds to fully understand these 6 lines of code. It will take 10 minutes to dive through all yours.

And this isn't any less flexible. In fact it's more so. You can trivially add new rules to this 6 line method. That is *not* the case with your code. Your patterns require adding 20 extra lines of boilerplate that then has to be tested and presents more opportunities for mistakes.

And look how I dealt with the regular expression impenetrability:

- Encode as many rules as possible outside the regex.
- Only use one fairly simple, *appropriately named and documented* regex for just the one check: that it matches the character classes. That and a comment are all you need.

---

If you are completely dead set against regular expressions, consider this LINQ based alternative:

```
public static bool IsValid(string s)
{
    return (
        s.Length >= 6 && s.Length <= 16
        && s.All(c => Char.IsLetterOrDigit(c) || '-' == c)
        && s.Count(c => c == '-') <= 1
        && Char.IsLetter(s, 0)
        && s[s.Length - 1] != '-'
    );
}
```

Comment: I'd tend to agree to use a single regex but in that case everything can be expressed with a single regex without any other surrounding code (including the length and the first/last character)

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Yes, but then it's not simple anymore. Putting most of these checks outside the regex vastly improves readability for very little cost.

Comment: Hmmmmm POV, I guess. To me a well written regex can express clearly the requirement while `UnicodeLettersNumsHyphen` has the _disadvantages_ of regexes (less easy to write and read) without its advantages (concise, fast and complete). Nitpick: I'd change `UnicodeLettersNumsHyphen` to a meaningful name because you can't understand what the regex is for without fully _decoding_ it.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti I added documentation instead of making the name too complicated.

Comment: Honestly I like it even less (and I wouldn't replace a good descriptive name with a comment) but as I said it's really just my POV

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Don't get me wrong. I love descriptive names. I made this one pretty descriptive, if not perfectly so. I just don't think it's possible to capture the entire description in the name without making it take up nearly the whole line.

Comment: _I promise you that 2 years down the line, anyone reading this code (including you!) will be much happier understanding the 5 liner than your code._ - this is so not true. I wouldn't let this code pass to production.

Comment: _Your patterns require adding 20 extra lines of boilerplate that then has to be tested and presents more opportunities for mistakes._ - not that _has to be tested_ but one that **can be tested**. Your code isn't testable and is so easy to make a mistake there that you wouldn't notice until something goes wrong for the client. This isn't an improvement. It's a great degradation of both readability and testability.

Comment: @t3chb0t This is testable...

Comment: @t3chb0t How is this not testable? You literally just have the test call the method and check the output without any boilerplate setup; that's maximum testability. Every line of code is an additional possibility for a mistake and therefore a bug. Every line of code is another line a reader has to understand. How can you look at this code and think it's harder to understand than 50 lines of extra methods? It's literally just a short list of conditions to check, **just like the requirements are**. What are the *practical* disadvantages of this code you're concerned about?

Comment: I partially agree with t3, I don't think this is "not testable" but I think that (assuming you will have similar requirements for different properties) writing ad-hoc code like this will make testing MUCH harder. Don't take me wrong, in your tests you will need to go through all the requirements (for each property), this isn't changed, but you want (must) test corner cases. And corner cases when handling text are A LOT and not so _corner_. Having reusable functions (NOT the way OP did but more general, even if - at first - you have to write more code) lets you test all those cases just ONCE.

Comment: Let me add an example. Unfortunately requirements are _vague_ and open to interpretation so let's assume - for the sake of discussion - that _letter_ has the meaning an average Joe would assume (not a programmer who might think that it's a synonym for a Latin US-ASCII character). In this case this simple string "" passes your length validation test (because each  is encoded as two UTF-16 code units then for your code its length is 6) and it's wrongfully rejected by `Char.IsLetterOrDigit()`. You obviously don't want to repeat this kind of tests each time you have length validation.

Comment: If you are thinking that "" is not a _letter_ (!) and it's rightfully rejected then you should try with "ā" (LATIN SMALL LETTER A MACRON): it's accepted. If you think "ā" is OK but "" is not) then you should try with "ā" (LATIN SMALL LETTER A + COMBINING MACRON): it's rejected. As you can see to write some more code to handle (and test) this correctly once and for all is a VERY good investment.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Your objections boil down to "Unicode is hard," and that is 100% true, especially when you get into the realm of combining characters. But deal with those problems with this method is not any harder. The OP's code notably suffer these same problems, and it's *even harder* to detect them because the logic is so scattered. If dealing with those cases led to a level of complexity where inlining each check became unwieldy, I'd obviously factor the checks out into a separate static method. But until it *does* become that complex, there's no reason to insist on separating them.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti And in fact, it would be harder to *fix* these problems with the OP's code because it's designed to process one character at a time. You'd have to change that fact to deal with combining characters, which means scrapping every line of code he has. Would you rather scrap 7 lines of code like my method or scrap 50 like his? These problems demonstrate that the time spent on all the OP's boilerplate was not a good investment.

Comment: I agree that OP took it the wrong way, that's why in the comment I wrote (emphasis added now): _"...Having reusable... **NOT the way OP did**..."_.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Okay, fine, but that's only reinforcing my point. Abstract when the complexity grows and not before. Simple *is* better when it's possible.

Comment: I agree but only if you have to validate one single property.